# Command manual in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

Is there a collection set or a reference manual of commands in Dymola? For example, if I wanna know the current working directory, which command should I use? I tried `pwd` and `dir`, but they didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a package called "Dymola Commands" or "DymolaCommands" in the package browser (at least since Dymola 2018).

You can open it as any other package, and either browser through the commands or right-click and use "Search" (tick "Full documentation").

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple sources to find commands which I check - in no special order - when it comes to finding a new command:

1. In Dymola 2020x the 'User Manual 1B' contains a section '2.5.19 Built-in functions in Dymola' which gives a good overview on the topic.
2. When starting Dymola a library called `DymolaCommands` will automatically be loaded. This can be searched using the package browser's 'Search' entry (by right-clicking on `DymolaCommands` -> Search).
3. In the Commands window you can call the function `listfunctions()`  to get an overview of the functions which can be called natively from Dymola's command line. Usually it makes most sense to search the text using CTRL+F afterwards.
4. Libraries can also provide useful functions. As an example the Modelica Standard Library provides the package `Modelica.Utilities` in which e.g. `Modelica.Utilities.Streams.print` can be used to debug models by plotting strings to the simulation log. Another one that can be pretty useful is the library `ModelManagement`.

There are multiple possibilities to get the current directory.

1. `cd()`: Unfortunately this will only print the directory to the command output and return `true`. So this is more for manual checks, although the output can be retrieved by `getLastError()`. Also this is Dmyola specific.
2. Using the Modelica Standard Library these are the commands that shall be used for managing the working directory: `Modelica.Utilities.System.getWorkDirectory()` and `Modelica.Utilities.System.setWorkDirectory()`
3. In case you want to get the directory of the currently executed script, the function `classDirectory()` will do that, using Dymola >2021.

Comment: And in which of all these resources are the commands `pwd()` and `ls()`, as asked by OP, to be found...?

Comment: Added it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! So I gather there is no `ls()` command, which would list the files in the current folder, as `dir` does on Windows?

Comment: You can use `Modelica.Utilities.System.command()` which will enable you to run any command from the OS's command line. But the output will only be `true` or `false`, so some additional effort will be necessary to get the desired output. I'll try to find out if there is a more efficient way...

Comment: To have the output of system commands like `ls` available in the Modelica tool, you have to redirect the output to a file, then read the file: `Modelica.Utilities.System.command("ls > out.txt"); Modelica.Utilities.Streams.readFile("out.txt")`